# jQuery slider script works locally, breaks on server

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, prefixfree

I'm stumped: a landing page that I built works perfectly locally, but completely breaks when I upload it to our server.

Here's the page: http://register.lot18.com/slider/google/

The white box in the middle is supposed to be perfectly centered; as you progress through each step of the form, the next step is supposed to slide in from the right. The positioning/sliding is done with `/js/slider.js` and jQuery UI. If you download the page and view it on your local machine, it should look exactly right.

Where do I even start with debugging this? The page already works locally, so basically everything I'm trying is just a random guess.

Even stranger: it doesn't break 100% of the time. If I sit there and keep refreshing the page, maybe 1 out of every 10 attempts, it'll display perfectly. Then I refresh and it's broken again.

---

UPDATE: Here's screenshots of what I'm seeing, both from Safari 6 on OS X:

Local: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/547222/lp-local.jpg
Server: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/547222/lp-server.jpg

---

UPDATE 2: When I remove PrefixFree (`js/prefixfree.min.js`), the page renders as if there is *no* stylesheet at all – but again, *only* on the server and not locally. A side effect of PrefixFree is that it takes external stylesheets and inserts them inline on the page. So is the external stylesheet not getting served with the correct `content-type` or something?

---

UPDATE 3: When I try to validate the CSS by direct URI, I get this error from the W3C validator:

`I/O Error: Unknown mime type : binary/octet-stream`

What does that mean?

Comment: Just tested on my machine and it works fine.

Comment: @Rhys: which browser and version? I've tested in both Safari 6 and Firefox 15.

Comment: Odd, if I open and close the developer console it centers itself, but when the page loads it's off to the left side.

Comment: @j08691: yep, I see the exact same thing. It's because in `/js/slider.js`, it repositions everything whenever the window dimensions change. But it initializes with the wrong position...but only on the server, not locally.

Comment: In your script.js file, try adding a `sealPosition();` after the first instance of `$(".step:eq(3)").right();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it...the CSS is being served up with the wrong MIME type: `binary/octet-stream` instead of `text/css`. I never noticed this because I use a jQuery plugin called PrefixFree on the page, and a side effect of using it is that your external stylesheets get inserted as inline styles on the page after the document loads.

I took PrefixFree out and bam, the page loads with no styling whatsoever.

So, the position is off because `slider.js` is actually calculating it *before* the styles are loaded through PrefixFree.

I need someone else to set the correct MIME type on the server for me, so I can't confirm this 100%, but I'm certain that's what the problem is.

---

UPDATE: It's an issue specifically with [S3 and Transmit on OS X](http://logbook.route19.com/post/8827368890/amazon-s3-content-type-problems-with-transmit). In Transmit preferences, set a custom upload header for CSS (content-type: text/css) and the problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

You have declared a number of functions inside the `$(document).ready` call but you can probably move these outside.

One thing that may be the cause of you trouble is when you attach the function call to `$(window).resize` you call `sealPosition()` but this is declared below it.

We had some odd issues declaring things after attaching them in anonymous functions like that. Try moving the sealPosition declaration above the `resize` attach or outside the `ready` call.

Answer (score 0):

It seems triggering a resize event (`$(window).resize()`) centers the dialog. I suggest, as @dave-anderson mentioned, re-arranging the centering code a little:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // [code as normal here]

    $(window).resize(function(){
        positionOnResize();
    });
    positionOnResize(); // initial positioning

}); // end document ready

function sealPosition() {
    var stepPosition = $(".step:eq(1)").position();
    $("#seal").css({
        left: stepPosition.left + 470,
        top: stepPosition.top - 80
    });
}

function dialogPosition() {
    $(".step:eq(0)").left();
    $(".step:eq(1)").center();
    $(".step:eq(2)").right();
    $(".step:eq(3)").right();
}

function positionOnResize() {
    dialogPosition();
    sealPosition();
}
```